# why my AJAX request fail when i just do a get request to a api that expose it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

im using [this](http://dicionario-aberto.net/estaticos/api.html) api, it's a dictionary, basicly the api let me do some get request and get details about a specific word that i type, with the word i got some details about the same, it actually worked but just with json, with xml i had a CORS problem that i don't know why, but the problem now is, that i am trying to do a simple get request using the suffix and prefix like this:

**html**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dicionário Online</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Dicionário Online</h1>

        <div class="">
            <span class="btns">
                <button type="button" id="btnDicionario">Significado</button>
              </span>
            palavra: <input type="text" placeholder="Palavra" id="procuraPalavra">
            prefixo: <input type="text" placeholder="Palavra" id="prefixo">
            sufixo: <input type="text" placeholder="Palavra" id="sufixo">
        </div>

        <div class="resposta">
            <div class="palavra"></div>
            <div class="etimologia"></div>
            <div id="texto"></div>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**javascript**

```
var palavra = $("procuraPalavra").val();

    $("#btnDicionario").click(function () {

        if ($("#procuraPalavra").val() == "") {
            var sufixo = $("#sufixo").val();
            var prefixo = $("#prefixo").val();
            if (sufixo != "" && prefixo != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json/',
                    data:{
                        prefix: prefixo,
                        suffix: sufixo
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: sucessCalbackPreSuf,
                    error: errorCalbackPreSuf
                });
            }
        }

    function sucessCalbackPreSuf(data) {
        $(data.list).each(function(index,element){
            $(".palavra").append("<p>" + element + "</p>");
        })

    }
    function errorCalbackPreSuf(req, status, err) {
        console.log("palavra nao existe");
    }
```

i just keep getting the CORS policy problem, the thing is that it happens sometimes to me because i was doing something wrong, what i actually believe is my problem again, can i get some help :S

Comment: Type changing the dataType from `json` to `jsonp`

Comment: well still not working, i suspect he doesn't even enter my callback functions now, it doesn't print anything just a red line with GET, but CORS error not showing anymore

Comment: Are you debugging this in browser? Try sticking some break points on the callbacks

Comment: yes i am, i have both callbacks with a console.log but it doesn't enter on anyone feels strange

Comment: Okay if you go into this error "red line with GET, but CORS error not showing anymore" what is the response packet and what is the http error number?

Comment: jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 GET http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json/prefix=a&suffix=a?callback=jQuery110106326251503431011_1486046423363&prefix=a&suffix=a&_=1486046423364 
send @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ inc.js:10
dispatch @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:5
v.handle @ jquery-1.10.1.min.js:5

Comment: that error, no number :S

Comment: Is there an error in the network tab of your browser [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx) [Chrome](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console--net-28167)

Comment: actually i found part of the solution the url is different: http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json?suffix=er&prefix=x          it is like this, how can i put the link in the url and pass the data with ajax?

Comment: I would stringify the data attribute `data: JSON.stringify({prefix: prefixo, suffix: sufixo})` something like this?